# Initialize local static array with non-constant data work-around

Tags: c, static, initialization

Recently I had the need to initialize a local static array with a non-constant contents (that is non-constant at compile-time, but known at the time the function was called the first time).

Hence, I wanted to do this (as a minimal reproducible example):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x;
int y;

void func(void)
{
    static int a[] = {x, y};   // <-- Error: initializer element is not constant
    printf("%d %d\n", a[0], a[1]);
}

int main()
{
    x = 2;
    y = 3;
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

I will post my work-around as an answer, but I wonder if there may be a smarter way.

Comment: This can't be done because `x` and `y` hold no meaningful values at the point where the static array is to be initialized. Such a program would depend on the internal order in which variables with static storage duration are initialized before main() is called. That is, you have to realize that the line `static int a[] = {x, y}; ` is actually executed _before_ main() is called and not when you enter the function. So this is an "XY problem", the correct solution is not to use a weird design such as this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

A non-static array can be initialized with non-constant data, so one solution is to initialize the static array with the contents of a non-static array the first time the function is run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int x;
int y;

void func(void)
{
    // static int a[] = {x, y};  // Error: initializer element is not constant
    int aInit[] = {x,y};
    static int a[sizeof(aInit)/sizeof(aInit[0])];
    static bool initDone = false;
    if(!initDone)
    {
        memcpy(a, aInit, sizeof(a));
        initDone = true;
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", a[0], a[1]);
}

int main()
{
    x = 2;
    y = 3;
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

Note: if `func` is known only to be run once, then all lines with `initDone` can be removed.

Comment: `memcpy` is assignment, not initialization. Apart from that, you don't need to declare an object, you could use a compound literal: `static int a[ sizeof (int[]){x,y} / sizeof(int)];`.

Comment: This code is not threadsafe